# Getting ID of last insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am implementing an auto save feature which saves every minute on a form that is being edited or created.

I am doing an insert of a `null` value beforehand in an auto-incremented db table. From here after the `null` insert, I need to retrieve the `id` that was inserted so that I can update off of that ID. How Can I go along of getting this ID with the code I have provided?

I have tried using `mysqli_insert_id` as shown below, but no luck.

```
// insert null into database to create the save point
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test_table (name, email, notes) VALUES ('x', 'x', 'x')"))
{
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare Auto-Save SQL statement.";
}

//GET LAST ID
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysqli_insert_id());
```

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php `printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", mysqli_insert_id($link));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting as a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

```
printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", mysqli_insert_id($mysqli));
```

You didn't pass your db connection to it.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Object oriented style

> mixed $mysqli->insert_id;

Procedural style

> mixed mysqli_insert_id ( mysqli $link )

Answer (score -1):

//this query will get the auto increment value of the specific table

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'tblname';
```